# Can't get to top row hot questions

Tags: bug, ios-app

The hot questions feed (the lightning bolt icon on the left just under my profile icon) doesn't accept taps on the large hot questions at the top, so I can't go to them from there.

The smaller hot questions below the large top row work fine.

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Cellular)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)